# Why the last element of the foreach loop is not displayed correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

in the double foreach loop below, the last element is not displayed vertically. I do not see why?

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ positioning }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \cc [count=\ci]  in { 
{0 , 0 , 0 , 0},
{0 , 0 , 0 , 1},
{0 , 0 , 1 , 0},
{0 , 0 , 1 , 1},
{0 , 1 , 0 , 0}, 
{0 , 1 , 0 , 1},
{0 , 1 , 1 , 0}
 }{
\foreach \nn [count=\ni] in \cc {
\node[below right= \ni em and \ci em]{\nn};
}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you if you add an empty element (simply add comma after the last `0}`)?

Comment: Just add `%` after the last element. Otherwise the parser gets confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do the Ulrike-Fischer trick, i.e. add a `%` at the right place, it works.

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ positioning }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \cc [count=\ci]  in { 
{0 , 0 , 0 , 0},
{0 , 0 , 0 , 1},
{0 , 0 , 1 , 0},
{0 , 0 , 1 , 1},
{0 , 1 , 0 , 0}, 
{0 , 1 , 0 , 1},
{0 , 1 , 1 , 0}%
 }{
\foreach \nn [count=\ni] in \cc {\typeout{\nn}
\node[below right= \ni em and \ci em]{\nn};
}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]